AWS Fargate & Fargate spot
I have some containers running on ECS Fargate now i have moved them to ECS Fargate Spot. while creating Service i add another capacity provider as fargate spot and their configs are as follows.
for Fargate : Base = 0 & Weight = 1
for Fargate Spot : Base = 1 & Weight = 2
with these configurations i managed to run the containers on ECS Fargate Provider I can confirm it from the Task Details Capacity Provider is Fargate Spot there.
Now issue is this I want to confirm when my ECS Fargate Spot Goes Down my containers will be moved to ECS Fargate ?
Another rhing I read in the AWS Documentation they said that when Fargate spot goed Down we send an event so where they send this event how can i Identify that event Because if i know the event i can write a Lambda function to trigger on this event and shift my containers to Fargate when Fargate spot stops. Some one please Help me on This.
I Have Tried Checking events for tasks but there is no such event like Fargate Spot goed down or services are shifted back to Fargate.

I believe this does exactly what you are looking for: fargate spot fallback
It is getting the event from Amazon ECS service action events, as you can see an example defined in the constructs code here.
